# Modelling a symmetric relation of types like (std::plus,std::minus) with templates possible?

Tags: c++, templates, template-meta-programming

Is it possible to define (unordered) pairs of types in c++(20) in a way that allows to find such a pair by providing any of its members at compile time?

This is trivial to achieve by either manually defining two ordered pairs for each unordered pair or by defining the complete set of pairs at one location, for example as template parameters of a tuple:

Definition of pair (A,B) via a specialization:

```
template<>
struct find_pair<A> {
    using p = std::pair<A,B>;
};

template<>
struct find_pair<B> {
    using p = std::pair<A,B>;
};
```

Get (A,B):

```
find_pair<A>::p
```

or

```
find_pair<B>::p
```

Definition of the complete set of pairs via variadic template:

```
template<typename A, typename B, typename ... X>
struct some_binary_relation : some_binary_relation<X...> {
    template<>
    static std::pair<A,B> p<A>();

    template<>
    static std::pair<A,B> p<B>();
};
using rel1 = some_relation<A,B,F,G,M,N>;
decltype(rel1::p<G>()) x //std::pair<F,G>
```

The advantage of approach #1 is that each definition of a pair can be made separate but requires redundant/bloated syntax.
Approach #2 requires each type to be written only once but one has to manually collect all the pairs in a template parameter list (inflexible).

Is it possible to do that in a way s.t. the pair definitions can be made seperate of each other
and no duplicate code within a pair definition is necessary?

Of course, no two distinct pairs must contain the same type and searching for non-existent pairs does not have to be supported.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you actually look for, but this might be useful:

```
#include <utility>

namespace pair {
template<class T> struct Type {};

template<class A, class B>
struct Pair {
    Pair(Type<A>);
    Pair(Type<B>);

    using type = std::pair<A, B>;
};

} // pair

namespace detail {

void FindPairImpl(...);

template<class A>
auto FindPairImpl(pair::Type<A> a) -> typename decltype(RegisterPair(a))::type;

} // namespace detail

template<class PairedType>
using FindPair = decltype(detail::FindPairImpl(pair::Type<PairedType>()));
```

Customization points: declare function `Pair<Type1, Type2> RegisterPair(Pair<Type1, Type2>)` in `pair` namespace.

Then use `FindPair` metafunction to find pair for type:

```
namespace pair { auto RegisterPair(Pair<double, const char *> a) -> decltype(a); }

int main() {
    static_assert(std::is_same<FindPair<int>, void>::value);
    static_assert(std::is_same<FindPair<double>, std::pair<double, const char *>>::value);
    static_assert(std::is_same<FindPair<const char *>, std::pair<double, const char *>>::value);
}
```